# TokenService is not visible from class loader

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I have keycloak extension (.war), what have dependency from keycloak-admin-client:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I have class what building instance of Keycloak:

```java
public class KeycloakAdminClientHelper {

    private static String MASTER_REALM = "master";
    private static String CLIENT_ID = "admin-cli";

    private Params params;
    private Keycloak keycloak;

    public KeycloakAdminClientHelper(Params params) {
        this.params = params;
        initKeycloak();
    }

    private void initKeycloak() {
        try {
            keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                    .serverUrl(params.getUrl())
                    .realm(MASTER_REALM)
                    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                    .username(params.getLogin())
                    .password(params.getPassword())
                    .build();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
        try {
            keycloak.realm(params.getRealm()).toRepresentation();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Keycloak getKeycloak() {
        return keycloak;
    }
}
```

It's deployed well, but when I'm call constructor (and initKeycloak()) I'm got "**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface TokenService in not visible from class loader**".

I tried to include keycloak-admin-client into modules (*$KEYCLOAK_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/...*), but got same exception.

I found some links about that on [github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/2443) and [JBoss issues](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2721). As I can see problem was solved but I got it anyway.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding client adapter in your application?

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Excuse me, but what do you mean about "client adapter"?